# How to get all Azure App Registration Owned by Login In User Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

Using PowerShell, we need to find out which Azure AD App Registration has an owner who is the logged-in user. Based on our research there is no PowerShell command that returns all Azure AD App Registration based on Owner. The [Get-AzureADApplicationOwner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadapplicationowner?view=azureadps-2.0) only returns the owners of one specified Azure AD App Registration.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution:

```
function isAzureADApplicationOwner ($azureApp, $ownerAccount) {
    $getOwners = $azureApp | Get-AzureADApplicationOwner
    foreach ($owner in $getOwners) {
        if ($owner.UserPrincipalName -eq $ownerAccount) {
            return  $True
        }
    }
    return  $False
} 
   

$Credential = Get-Credential
$azureConnection = Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
$apps = @()

$getallApps = Get-AzureADApplication -All $true # get all App Registrations

foreach ($eachApp in $getallApps) {
  if (isAzureADApplicationOwner -azureApp $eachApp -ownerAccount $azureConnection.Account.Id) {
    $apps += $eachApp
  } 
}
```